# Is it a good idea to keep all the enums in one place?

Tags: c#, .net

When I'm building a class library I usually create a file Enums.cs to hold all the enums used in the assembly. Here is an example:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public enum Colors
    {
        Red,
        Green,
        Blue
    }
    public enum Shapes
    {
        Circle,
        Square,
        Triangle
    }
}
```

This makes all my enums easy to find, well organized and easy to access in code.

I'm wondering if there is any reason why this would not be such a good idea?

Comment: I always keep my enums all in one place, or I can't find them when I'm ready to go out. They're all in a bowl by the front door.

Comment: A lot of good answers, thanks everyone... Although it appears that a big chunk of it boils down to personal preference, I do think that not arranging by kind but by modularity makes a lot of sense and is in line with the way the framework itself is organized. It doesn't hurt that it sounds like something out of Cwalina's seminal "Framework Design Guidelines" and it got the most up votes so I'll mark that as the answer...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's generally better to arrange definitions by modularity, rather than by kind.

Comment: yep, and when it's arranged by modularity then you can arrange by kind... depends on the complexity of your application

Answer (score 15):

I personally think this is not a good idea.  I prefer to keep enums in their own file (one file per defined enum), just like a class.  This makes it more obvious (to me) where to go if I'm looking for a type, by name.  I treat enums just like a class or struct, or any other namespace-scoped type, which for me means one type per file.

The main downside to your approach arises if you have many Enums defined in your project - that "one file" can get quite large.

However, there is no technical difference in the compiled IL.  This really is more of a personal, organizational strategy.

Comment: You meant, one file for each enum?

Comment: @kzen: Yeah - separate file per.

Comment: Are these files mixed with other class files or do you create a subfolder to hold all the enum files?

Comment: Having them in separate file also eases multiple checkout conflict resolution and branch integration. All IDEs make the actual file location of the enum pretty irrelevant (ie. they find/jump to the definition location immediately) so there are no serious drawbacks in having multiple files.

Comment: @Remus: Exactly.  I see a few disadvantages, and no real advantages, to putting them all in one file...

Comment: @kzen: I don't make separate folders.  I have one subfolder per namespace, with all of the namespace types in place.  (This keeps my folder structure in line with the object browser..)  If you can't find your type in a folder because you have that many types, it's time to start considering moving things into separate namespaces, IMO.

Comment: @Reed: Do you have a file naming convention that allows you to quickly detect these enums and/or group them?

Comment: @kzen: I give them a very clean, clear name (based on the .NET naming conventions).  This tends to make them very obvious.  Between this and Visual Studio, I've never had an issue...

Comment: @kzen: Why are you trying to "group" enums, btw?  If an enum really needs grouping, consider moving it into the class in question, and not having it global in the namespace scope.  Otherwise, if it's shared between multiple classes, it should be (in my opinion) a public type of the namespace, and as a result, deserves it's own file ;)  Enums deserve the same rights as other types :-D

Comment: @Reed: I like to keep the file count down to reduce the clutter so creating a file for each enum is just against my basic instincts...

Comment: @kzen: Smaller files are better for source control - more files are "clutter" - it's a balance you need to choose for your project and means.  Most large-scale, enterprise applications have a lot of files anyways, and having the better ingration with source control and better discoverability of multiple files more than makes up for having "extra file clutter"...  Personally, as I mentioned, if you get too many files in one folder, it means your namespace is getting crowded, and may need to be split anyways...

Answer (score 9):

Well, you could apply the same reasoning to all your delegate types, all your classes, all your structs.

By grouping things according to their significance to the compiler, you are losing the opportunity to group them in ways that are meaningful to *you*. The compiler already knows how to treat them according to their meaning in the language.

Personally when I want to find the declarations relevant to the "Parser" as opposed to the "Configuration Dialog", I go to the place where the code for that feature is kept. I don't have to look in five different places depending on the language features I'm using.

Comment: +1 I was about to write an answer which would have been very similar to this.

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends on what areas of the code they apply to. If I'm looking at a function in a particular class, I would expect the associated enums to be nearby.

Comment: What if multiple classes utilize the same enum?

Comment: If the enum is generic, then it should be in a generic place. But even if you look at the MS frameworks, stuff like Colors is still under System.Drawing, even though it's used from lots of other places.

Answer (score 2):

We typically have an entire project, assembly that houses all our *Constants, Enums, and helper Methods.*

So **YES**, I would recomend placing them in a central, easily accessable location.

This will allow you to easily access the assembly from other assemblies, trying to avoid circular references.

Comment: You put all of your enums in a separate *project?*

Comment: Enums that will be used in various other projects, yes.

Comment: Well that makes sense, but I read your answer as saying that *all* your enums go in a separate project (even project-specific ones).

Comment: I prefer the logical separation rather than having it all mixed in throughout the project. I don't think I'd put it into a separate project but I would likely put it in it's own namespace to keep things organized.

Answer (score 2):

I go for more of a Namespace organization. Visual Studio makes it too easy to navigate to an object's declaration.  It makes more sense to me to have an enum related to database/data access in my MyData namespace rather than some generic enum namespace, i could care less about the file name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a java developper but i think i can answer here too...

For me it's not a good idea. Like Daniel Earwicker said you could do the same for classes... you could handle your whole application in one single file with many inner classes (i assume in C# like in Java you can have inner classes...), but you don't do it anyway...

And an enum can sometime be a more complex structure, it can have attributes...

A (very) simple exemple in Java:

```
public enum JobPriority {
    HIGH(5),
    MEDIUM_HIGH(4),
    MEDIUM(3),
    MEDIUM_LOW(2),
    LOW(1)
    ;
    private int level;
    JobPriority(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
}
```

I work on a very big french website and we have enum structures a lot more complex than that... if we had all our enums in one single file this file would make hundreds of lines...

So if your application is small and enum structure is not complex, you can put all of them in one file.

But you'd rather put complex enums in single files on a enum namespace (package in java), and make a enum namespace when needed for each functional part of your application. For simple enums, why not adding then in a common enum file for a given namespace (you can have multiple common enums files). Dunno if it's a good practice.

Does it really matter to you to have many enum files?
If you need to find a enum, your IDE perhaps offer you fast class search for finding easily enums no? You can also suffix all your enums by xxxEnum.cs to distinguish them (and also find them all fastly by class name *Enum).

In the java webapp i'm working on (~2 million lines of code, hundreds of enums), we can easily find enums in our Eclipse IDE with shortcuts like ctrl+shift+R + *Enum. It's a lot faster than having common enum files :)

Answer (score 0):

There are certain code-file names that immediately raise a red flag for me. Along with `utils.cpp`, `helpers.vb` (or suchlike) if I see an `enums.cs` I immediately question whether a piece of software is becoming over coupled to enumerations.

Enumerations should be used sparingly and declared near the leaf (least type coupled) types that they are associated with.

Too often I have seen large systems that become over coupled because of shared enumerations. Before too long someone will have the bright idea to enumeration all of the database primary keys.